# Documents upload form is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created the below code for user file uploads, but it does not seem to be working.

Can anyone please suggest where  I am doing wrong.

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['store_id'])){
  header('Location: ../pooler_login.php');
 }
 else{
  $store_id=$_SESSION['store_id'];   
   //echo $store_id;
 } 
include_once("../config/db.php");

$result =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pooler WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($result) { //we have the product info 
    $email=$row['email'];
    $shop_name=$row['shop_name'];
    $shop_number=$row['shop_number'];
    $max_service=$row['max_service'];
    $tin_number=$row['tin_number'];
    $owner_name=$row['owner_name'];
    $mobile_number=$row['mobile_number'];
    $other_person_name=$row['other_person_name'];
    $other_mobile=$row['other_mobile'];
    $description=$row['description'];
    
   } 

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Update Profile</title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/syntax/shCore.css">

<style type="text/css" class="init"></style>
<!-- script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ymsdemos.net78.net/gmap/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/demo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
 $(document).ready(function(){$('.tab').dataTable();});
</script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, fastIframe:false, width:"1100px", height:"660px", transition:"fade", scrolling   : true});
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            #cboxOverlay{ background:#666666; }
        </style>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.geocomplete.js"></script>
 <style>
 .mintxt {
  width: 297px;
  margin: 0px 3px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.labeltxt{
 margin-left:200px;
}
.paneltitle{
 width:100%;
 margin-left:430px;
 font-size:20px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <!-- <div class="main"> <div class="innerheader">
     <div class="width">
         <div class="inlogo fl">
             <img src="images/logo.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="inmenus fr">
             
            </div>
            <div class="cl"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="instantmenus">
     <?php include('menu.php');?>
    </div> -->
    <div class="container">     <div class="grandheading">Upload Documents</div> 
 
        <div class="width" style="min-height:500px;">
                    <center><?php if(isset($_COOKIE['deta']) && $_COOKIE['deta']!='')
        {
         
         echo "<span style='color:green;'>    ". $_COOKIE['deta']."    </span>"; 
         setcookie("deta","",time()-3600,"/","",0); 
        } 
       ?> <div id="response"></div></center>
            <div class="panel">
             <div class="paneltitle">Upload Documents</div>
    <!--<nav id="profiletabs">
                         <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#bio" title="My Profile" class="sel"><img width="40" src="images/My-profile.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" title="Edit Profile"><img width="40" src="images/edit_profile.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#friends" title="Change Password"><img width="40" src="images/change_password.png" /></a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>-->
                <div class="offerbox">
                 <form class="chargefrm" action="../admin/upload_infopooler.php" method="POST">
                 <table>
                      <tr>
                         <td><div class="labeltxt">Car Modal</div></td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="stxt number mintxt" name="shop_name" id="shop_name" placeholder=" " value=" " />
       
       </td>
                        </tr>
       <tr>
                         <td><div class="labeltxt">Car color</div></td>
                            <td><input type="textl" class="stxt number mintxt" name="email" id="email" placeholder=" " value=" " /></td>
                        </tr>
      
                        <tr>
                         <td><div class="labeltxt">Permnant Address</div></td>
                            <td><textarea class="stxt  mintxt" name="service" id="service"rows="3" cols="10" placeholder="" value=" " ></textarea>  </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                         <td><div class="labeltxt">Company</div></td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="stxt number mintxt" name="shop_number" id="shop_number" placeholder="shop_number" value=" " /></td>
                        </tr>
      <tr>
                         <td><div class="labeltxt">Driving License</div></td>
                            <td><input type="file" class="stxt number mintxt" name="tin_number" id="tin_number" placeholder="TIN Number" value=" " />
                            File shoud be in pdf
                            </td>
                        </tr>
      
                         <tr>
                         <td><div class="labeltxt">Vehicle Documents</div></td>
                            <td><input type="file" class="stxt  mintxt" name="owner_name" id="owner_name" placeholder="Owner Name" value="<?php echo $owner_name;?>" /> 
                            File should be in pdf
                             </td>
                        </tr>
                       
      <tr>
                         <td><div class="labeltxt">Upload Photo</div></td>
                            <td><input type="file" class="stxt  mintxt" name="other_person_name" id="other_person_name" placeholder="Second Owner Name" value=" " />
                             File should be in pdf
                              </td>
                        </tr>
                         
                         <td></td>
                            <!-- <td><input type="button" class="btn smbtn" name="submit" value="Update Information" id="update_btn" onclick="savecharges()" /></td>-->
                                 <td><input type="submit" class="btn smbtn" name="submit" value="Update Information" id="update_btn" onclick="savecharges()" /></td>
                            
                        </tr> 
                    </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="chargesajax"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
     function savecharges()
     {
      $max_service=$("#service").val();
      $shop_number=$("#shop_number").val();
      $tin_number=$("#tin_number").val();
      $owner_name=$("#owner_name").val();
      $email=$("#email").val();
      $other_person_name=$("#other_person_name").val();
      $shop_name=$("#shop_name").val();
      //$description=$("#description").val();
      //$description=$("#description").val();
      $('#response').html("<img src='../img/loaders/load.GIF'><br>loading....");
      
      //window.location =  '../admin/upload_infopooler.php?shop_name='+$shop_name'&email='+$email'&max_service='+$max_service+'&shop_number='+$shop_number+'&tin_number='+$tin_number+'&owner_name='+$owner_name+'&other_person_name='+$other_person_name; 
       alert('hello');   
       $.post('admin/upload_infopooler.php.php', {max_service: $max_service, shop_number:$shop_number, tin_number:$tin_number, description:$description, owner_name:$owner_name, other_person_name:$other_person_name, mobile_number:$mobile_number,other_mobile:$other_mobile}, function(data){
             
       $('#response').html(data);
   
      
       }*/
     }
     savecharges();
    </script>
            </div>
            
           
        </div>  
    </div> 
        <div class="footer">
         
            <div class="cl"></div>
            
            <div class="copyright">Copyright@ rainbowinfotech.in</div>
            
          
        </div>
        
    </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#profiletabs ul li a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var newcontent = $(this).attr('href');
    
    $('#profiletabs ul li a').removeClass('sel');
    $(this).addClass('sel');
    
    $('#content section').each(function(){
      if(!$(this).hasClass('hidden')) { $(this).addClass('hidden'); }
    });
    
    $(newcontent).removeClass('hidden');
  });
});
</script>
</body>

<!-- Mirrored from ymsdemos.net78.net/gmap/updateoffers.php by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], Fri, 24 Apr 2015 09:21:33 GMT -->
</html>
<script>
   $(function(){
  $(".geocomplete").geocomplete({
   map: ".map_canvas",
   details: "form div",
   detailsAttribute: "data-geo",
   /*types: ["(cities)"],*/
   country:'in'
  });
   });
</script> 

<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

---

```
 <?php
 include('../config/db.php');

    $store_id=$_REQUEST['id'];
    $max_service=$_REQUEST['max_service'];
    $shop_number=$_REQUEST['shop_number'];
    $shop_name=$_REQUEST['shop_name'];
    $tin_number=$_REQUEST['tin_number'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $owner_name=$_REQUEST['owner_name'];
    $other_person_name=$_REQUEST['other_person_name'];
    //$mobile_number=$_REQUEST['mobile_number'];
    //$other_mobile=$_REQUEST['other_mobile'];
    //echo $max_service;
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     if(!empty($_REQUEST['tin_number']) && !empty($_REQUEST['max_service']) && !empty($_REQUEST['shop_number']) && !empty($_REQUEST['owner_name']) && !empty($_REQUEST['other_person_name']) && !empty($_REQUEST['shop_name']) && !empty($_REQUEST['email']))
    {
    $sql="insert into uploaddoc(carmodal,carcolor,addr,company) values('$shop_name','$email','$max_service','$shop_number')";
    $res=mysql_query($sql);
    if($res)
    {
        echo "record added successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "something wrong";
    }

    /**** Upload Files Driving Licence ****/
     define ("FILEREPOSITORY","./");
      if (isset($_FILES['tin_number'])) 
      {
         if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['tin_number']['tmp_name'])) 
                {
              if ($_FILES['tin_number']['type'] != "application/pdf")
                  {
                        echo "<p>File must be uploaded in PDF format.</p>";
                  } 
                 else
                  {
                     $today ="/pdfdrivelic/";
                     if (! is_dir(FILEREPOSITORY.$today))
                 {
                          mkdir(FILEREPOSITORY.$today);
                 }
                     $name = $_POST['name'];
                     $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['tin_number']['tmp_name'], FILEREPOSITORY.$today."/"."$name.pdf");
                if ($result == 1) 
                               echo "<p>File successfully uploaded.</p>";
                        else 
                                   echo "<p>There was a problem uploading the files.</p>";
                     }
                       }
              }
     /**** Upload Files Vehicle Documents ****/
         define ("FILEREPOSITORY","./");
     if (isset($_FILES['owner_name']))
     {
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['owner_name']['tmp_name'])) 
              {
                           if ($_FILES['owner_name']['type'] != "application/pdf")
                 {
                        echo "<p>File must be uploaded in PDF format.</p>";
                 } 
                      else
                 {
                     $today ="/pdfvehicle/";
                     if (! is_dir(FILEREPOSITORY.$today))
                      {
                         mkdir(FILEREPOSITORY.$today);
                      }
                     $name = $_POST['name'];
                     $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['owner_name']['tmp_name'], FILEREPOSITORY.$today."/"."$name.pdf");
                    if ($result == 1) 
                            echo "<p>File of vehicle successfully uploaded.</p>";
                        else 
                            echo "<p>There was a problem uploading the files.</p>";
                 }
              }
     }
if($_FILES['image'] != "jpg" && $_FILES['image'] != "png" && $_FILES['image'] != "jpeg" && $_FILES['image'] != "gif" && $_FILES["image"]["size"] > 2097152 ) 
{
    //echo "6";
    $Error="Invalid Image!";
}
else
{
                        $target_dir = "../poolerimage/";
                        $db_dir = "uploads/users/";
                        $date=date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
                        $datemd=md5($date);
                        $date=substr($datemd,2,-7);
                        //$unique_id=substr($date, 3, -3);
                        $target_file = $target_dir .$date. basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
                        //$user_image = $db_dir .$date. basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
                        //$pic=addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
                        $image=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
                        if($image==1)
                        {
                            echo "Image Uploaded Successfully.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "<p>There was a problem uploading the files.</p>";
                        }
}


                    header('Location: ../dashboard/uploaddoc.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Fill the required fields";
    }               
}                   
?>
```

Please let me know where is the error..

Comment: you are setting `$store_id=$_SESSION['store_id'];` but later you use `$id` in your query.

Comment: And that's way too much code to look through, please see [mcve]

Comment: First and foremost, your form does not have a valid enctype in order to process files (it's required when dealing with files) and I have stated that in my answer below. However and going over the rest of your code, have found a few more problems where I have made a few edits since my original post. It is unknown if you have seen what I added to it, so you will need to reload my answer. I did my best to help you out; the rest is up to you to further debug your code. Do go over it in its entirety.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Files processing require a valid enctype and your form/code does not contain it.

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` inside your `<form></form>` tags.

As per the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php
- **Also make sure the (upload) folder has proper permissions set to write to it.**

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

- Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to all `mysql_query()`.

---

**Nota:**

Add `exit;` after each header, otherwise your code may want to continue executing.

Also note that your code is open so SQL injection. Use a prepared statement.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

`mysql_` functions are deprecated and will be removed in PHP 7.0

---

Footnotes:

As stated in comments:

> *"you are setting $store_id=$_SESSION['store_id']; but later you use $id in your query. –  Gerald Schneider"*

I believe you would like to use `$store_id` rather than `$id` in your query.

- Error reporting would have thrown you an undefined variable id notice.
- `$_REQUEST['tin_number']` and `$_REQUEST['owner_name']`. That will give you trouble.
  Use `$_FILES` exclusively instead of `$_REQUEST`.

**N.B.:**
There is something else that I spotted and that is many `$_FILES["image"]`. There is no input matching it, so that part of your question is unclear and will fail you, as per what you posted for it in your original question.

---

Added notes.

If that still doesn't work for you, you will need to check for errors and use `var_dump();` - `print_r();` to see what's going through or not, and start with a new file just for uploading a single file. Once you've gotten that to work, you can then implement it in your code.

It's unclear as to what is inside:

```
include('../config/db.php');
```

Make sure you are using the same MySQL API used in your query, being `mysql_`. If it is `mysqli_` or PDO, then those different APIs do not intermix; *an insight.*

Although, `mysqli_` or PDO are recommended and using a prepared statement as I have already made a note about. If you do plan to go that route, remember not to mix different MySQL APIs/functions.